# ./gradlew desktop:run does not work but setting a configuration does : libgdx

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

When I run `./gradlew desktop:run` in the Android Studio terminal it fails to run. But when I set a run configuration (A Gradle task with the Gradle project being my project and run task being "desktop:run") it works perfectly fine. (Also the `./gradlew android:run` doesn't work either, it only works when I run the android configuration which is automatically created.)

`./gradlew desktop:run`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

`./gradlew android:run`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

EDIT: Some pages on the web suggested I use an older java version but that doesn't work.

build.gradle (project level):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'FPSCounter'
        gdxVersion = '1.6.4'
        roboVMVersion = '1.14.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.4.0'
        aiVersion = '1.5.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

build.gradle (core module):

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
```

build.gradle (desktop module):

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.udacity.gamedev.fpscounter.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

build.gradle (android module):

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.udacity.gamedev.fpscounter.android/com.udacity.gamedev.fpscounter.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are using a version of Gradle in the Gradle Wrapper that is too old to recognize JDK 10. When you run directly in Android Studio, it might be using its own Gradle version (I think there is a setting when importing a project that determines whether Android Studio will use the wrapped Gradle.)

So you can downgrade your JDK or upgrade your Gradle wrapper version. Downgrading the JDK is a pain because they've started removing older versions from the Sun download site. And you may have non-LibGDX stuff you want to work on with a newer JDK.

To upgrade the Gradle wrapper, open `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the file name at the end to `gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip`. At least, that's what I use and it works up to JDK 12.

Then you need to replace the `compile` keywords in your `build.gradle` file with `implementation`. And in `/desktop/build.gradle`, change the line `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)` to `from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)` (add an s on the end).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this set of instructions and inform you if it works.

Comment: even after changing the ```distributionUrl``` to ```https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip``` gradle doesn't recognize the method ```implementation```

Comment: So libGDX doesn't work when I upgrade the Gradle wrapper, so I downgraded the JDK to JDK 8. That worked, just now I have to juggle multiple JDKs and switch them out when I use a non-libGDX project.

Comment: Basically the build and sync fails because the libGDX version and the Gradle version aren't compatible. I can reproduce the error if you'd like a screenshot.

Comment: I haven't had any trouble using exclusively JDK 12 and Gradle 5.1.1 in my libgdx projects. It could have been some other detail we've missed here. But to avoid the pain of switching JAVA_HOME back and forth, I think you can add this to your gradle.properties file in your project: `org.gradle.java.home = path_to_jdk8_directory`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also, do you think that it could be the libGDX version causing problems? (I'm pretty sure I'm not using the latest version. Most of them are downloaded from GitHub...) Because I've tried using JDK 10.0.2 and Gradle 5.1.1  before asking this question.

Comment: GitHub has the latest LibGDX version 1.9.9, although I don't know how you would be using a downloaded version in a Gradle project.

Comment: I mean most of my libGDX projects, not the libGDX framework. But still- when I use the setup jar, the default Gradle version is 4.6. Changing this would cause an error. (Again, using JDK 10.0.2, and my downloaded projects use the libGDX version 1.6.8)

Comment: My answer above is what fixes the errors of changing the Gradle version for a new LibGDX project, at least the errors I've encountered.